# Delay refresh in web browser c#

Tags: c#, browser, refresh

How to delay refreshing the page in webBrowser? I use `Sleep` but this freezing my application

```
    for (int i = 0; i < iteruj; i++) 
    {                
        webBrowser1.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

How can I do this?

How to check the page is fully loaded?

Comment: On what purpose you are doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to refresh it every 10 seconds you can use Timer.

```
var timer = new Timer(state => webBrowser.Refresh(), null, 0, 10000);
```

When you want to stop refreshing use

```
timer.Dispose();
```